# How to get rid of automatically added HTML tags?

Tags: html, xslt

I have the following XSLT code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Component:SelectedCriteriaItem">
  <!--<xsl:if test="position() = 1">-->
  <ul class="filters-list">
    <li>
      <span class="value" id="occDisplayTitle">
        <xsl:value-of select="Component:Value"></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
        <img src="/COSimages/BusPortal/custom-x.png"  alt="Close Icon" height="14" width ="14">
          <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('javascript:FOSLeftNav_locationdelete(event,',$apos,Component:Value,$apos,')',';','return false;')"></xsl:value-of>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--</xsl:if>-->
</xsl:for-each>
```

which is inside a for loop. For the first item it's adding some junk HTML in the rendered HTML as follows:

```
<span id="occDisplayTitle" class="value">
12345 within 25 miles 
 <img<span class="truncate_ellipsis">...</img<span>
</span>
```

Actually its should rendered as

```
<span id="occDisplayTitle" class="value">
12345 within 25 miles 
 <img width="14" height="14" onclick="javascript:FOSLeftNav_locationdelete    (event,'12345    within 25 miles');return false;" alt="Close Icon"  src="/COSimages/BusPortal/custom-x.png">  </span>
```

but for the rest of the items it looks fine and is adding the correct image.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Where is the for loop? Are you using a programming language somewhere, e.g. PHP? Or some other software to make the HTML/XML?

Comment: Its xslt code. The for loop is inside the xslt.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you showed the entire code, including the actual loop construct.

Comment: Is your rendered html actually correct too? I can't see how your XSLT snippet could possibly render output that you have shown!

Comment: Do you get the same error if you comment out the onclick?